# Is there any common dimensions for a canvas with aspect ratios of 16:9 and 4:3/Vertically centering the canvas when the aspect ratio is 4:3

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, aspect-ratio

I have developed an application with 1366x768 with the aspect ratio 16:9, but in ipad which has 4:3 ratio, that application is not showing fully to the window size. there is some space at the bottom. We cannot fit to window as it will look weird.

How can i vertically center the canvas for 4:3 ratio instead of top. I tried using css to vertically center in jquery.

```
function sizeHandler()
{ 
    window.scrollTo(0, 1); 
    if (!$("#canvas")) 
    { return; } 
    var rw = CANVAS_WIDTH; 
    var rh = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
    var heightPercentage
    var w = window.innerWidth; 
    var h = window.innerHeight; 
    multiplier = Math.min((h / rh), (w / rw)); 
    var destW = rw * multiplier; 
    var destH = rh * multiplier;
    $("#canvas").css("width",destW+"px");
    $("#canvas").css("height",destH+"px");
    $("#canvas").css("left",((w / 2) - (destW / 2))+"px"); 

    var Ratio = Math.round(($(window).width() / $(window).height())*100)/100
    console.log("Ratio = "+Ratio)
    if (Ratio > 1.33 && Ratio <= 1.78) 
    {
          $("#canvas").css("-ms-transform","translateY(0%)"); 
          $("#canvas").css("transform","translateY(0%)"); 
          $("#canvas").css("top","0%");
          $("#canvas").css("padding-top","0%"); 
          $("#canvas").css("position","absolute");
     }
     if(Ratio <= 1.33) 
     {
          $("#canvas").css("-ms-transform","translateY(13.3%)");
          $("#canvas").css("transform","translateY(13.3%)"); 
          $("#canvas").css("top","50%"); $("#canvas").css("padding-top","0%"); $("#canvas").css("position","relative");
      }
};
```

I expect the canvas to be vertically center when the aspect ratio is 4:3 and when it is 16:9, it will fit to window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc to calculate the height of your element in CSS

```css
canvas{
  width:90vw;
  height:calc(9 * 90vw / 16);
  background:#d9d9d9;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;bottom:0; left:0;right:0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```